# Как избавиться от постоянного приведения типов? HashMap

Tags: java

Допустим, у нас еcть HashMap :

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> stash = new HashMap<>();
```

в stash кладутся элементы типа int как для ключа, так и для value
Теперь, допустим, нам нужно работать с этими значениями : делить какой-нибудь int на них. 
Т.е. пусть будет так :

```
 int amount;
...
for (Map.Entry stashEnrty : stash.enrtySet()) {
amount = amount / (int) stashEntry.getKey(); }
```

Допустим, таких мест в коде много, и приводить к типу int приходится много раз. Есть ли способы избежать этого?
В key и value добавляются значения, которые спарсили из String через Integer.parseInt()

Comment: А если... просто не ставить `(int)`? .-.Autounboxing не срабатывает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так?

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e : stash.entrySet()){
    amount = amount / e.getKey(); 
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что в Key и в value кидаются значения, которые спарсили из String через Integer.parseInt()

Comment: И что? У вас stash определен как `Map<Integer, Integer> stash`, это значит что все его `Map.Entry` будут `Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>`, а не `Map.Entry<Object, Object>`, `Integer.parseInt` возвращает `int` всегда, либо падает, если не может спарсить.

Comment: Integer.parseInt() возвращает Integer, именно поэтому если убрать каст  key к (int), компилятор будет ругаться и выдавать ошибку " '/' can not be applied to 'int' and 'Object' "

Comment: Это будет в случае вашего кода, в случае кода, приведенного в моем ответе все будет в порядке, при условии что `stash` у вас объявлен точно так, как объявлен в коде вопроса. Приводить руками `Integer` к `int` не нужно, это делается автоматически.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Теперь разобрался что к чему, спасибо еще раз